# Unable to show UserForm after refreshing data from an external sharepoint portal

Tags: forms, vba, sharepoint, refresh

I would like to ask for your help, I'm stucked with the following problem:

In my workbook there is a worksheet (owssvr) which is connetcting to a Sharepoint portal.
Data comes from there after refreshing.

I also have a UserForm (it's name is RM), which is a UI to help the users specify all filtering criteria.

The method is the following:

- when workbook opens it should refresh data from the extrenal Sharepoint portal (Workbook_Open sub), and after finishing this
- Userform (RM) should be opened.

Both are working separately (I mean the refreshing command and the userform works fine) until I try to run them after each other (refresh then show userform). After connecting to the Sharepoint site I am unable to show my form. The error message is the following:

Runtime Error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

Here are the relevant codes (checkpoints 1,2 and 3 are OK, error message comes after msgbox#3):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheets("owssvr").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
MsgBox "ok1"

Sheets("Start").Select
MsgBox "ok2"

Range("B2").Select
MsgBox "ok3"

Load RM
MsgBox "ok4"

RM.Show

End Sub
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

ACHM3D